# Proxy and ChromeOptions class with ChromeDriver is not working

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to use the ChromeOptions class along w/ the Proxy class to add a proxy to my ChromeDriver. The code has been written, the application runs, but when I do a 'what is my IP' - Google returns my home IP still......

```
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            var proxy = new Proxy();
            proxy.IsAutoDetect = false;
            proxy.Kind = ProxyKind.Manual;
            proxy.HttpProxy = "proxy_ip:proxy_port";
            options.Proxy = proxy;

            var Driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

            Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");
```